# Add two textbox contain and show the result in another textbox without any button using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 dynamic divisions. Each division holds some text boxes, among which every division has one set of particular text fields, where, if user put any data into the first text box within those set of textboxes then it should appear in a previous readonly text box which is not a part of those divisions. again if user put any data into the second text box within those set of textboxes, then their addition will be shown in the previous readonly text box.

Here I am going to attach the whole code which I have tried till now. But I couldn't get the desired result.

```
<%@page import="beans.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>div data entry</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div class="transbox">
<form action="dataentryservletclass" method="post">
<center>
<table><tr><td>Class Name</td> <td><input type="text" name="c_cname"></td>
<td>Class ID</td> <td><input type="text" name="c_cid" placeholder="Enter a Text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Class Start Date</td> <td><input type="date" name="c_csdate"></td>
<td>Total Marks</td> <td><input type="text" name="c_tmarks" id="txttotal" readonly></td>
</tr></table>
No. of Students <select class="selectbtn" name="c_nos" onchange="myFunction(this)">
<option>Select One</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="myDIV1" style="display:none">
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Student Roll No.</th>
<th>Marks Obtain</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sname1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sroll1"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt1" name="c_marks1" onclick="sum()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
<div id="myDIV2" style="display:none">
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Student Roll No.</th>
<th>Marks Obtain</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sname1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sroll1"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt1" name="c_marks1" onclick="sum()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sname2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sroll2"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt2" name="c_marks2" onclick="sum()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
<div id="myDIV3" style="display:none">
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Student Roll No.</th>
<th>Marks Obtain</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sname1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sroll1"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt1" name="c_marks1" onclick="sum()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sname2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sroll2"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt2" name="c_marks2" onclick="sum()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sname3"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c_sroll3"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt3" name="c_marks3" onclick="sum()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(objDrop) {
    var a = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
    var b = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
    var c = document.getElementById("myDIV3");
    if(objDrop.value=="1"){
        if (a.style.display === "none") {
            a.style.display = "block";
            b.style.display = "none";
            c.style.display = "none";
            } 
        else {
            a.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    else if(objDrop.value=="2"){
        if (b.style.display === "none") {
            a.style.display = "none";
            b.style.display = "block";
            c.style.display = "none";
            } 
        else {
            b.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    else if(objDrop.value=="3"){
        if (c.style.display === "none") {
            a.style.display = "none";
            b.style.display = "none";
            c.style.display = "block";
            } 
        else {
            c.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
}
function sum(){
    var x=document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var y=document.getElementById('txt2').value;
    var z=document.getElementById('txt3').value;
    if(x==""){
        x=0;
    }
    if(y==""){
        y=0;
    }
    if(z==""){
        z=0;
    }
    var result=parseInt(x)+parseInt(y)+parseInt(z);
    if(!isNaN(result)){
        document.getElementById('txttotal').value=result;
    }
}
</script>
</center>
<hr><hr>
<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbtn" style="float:right">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per my understanding, u enter marks in "Marks obtained textbox" than it need add and show in "total marks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mockup of what you described, using the onkeyup event to trigger the javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function display(){
            var resultBox = document.getElementById("resultbox");
            var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
            var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");

            var result = input1.value + input2.value;
            resultBox.value = result;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="resultbox" type="text" readonly />
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="input1" onkeyup="display();" onchange="display();" />
        <input type="text" id="input2" onkeyup="display();" onchange="display();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This code is working, but not in the case which I have described.

Comment: The problem I am running into when trying your code is that it the getElementById always returns the first match. So you have 3 inputs with id="txt1", off which it grabs the first one. Personally I would advise against using the same id for multiple elements. What you can instead do is put txt1-1, txt1-2 etc as ids and add all of the nonempty elements. Or use a more sophisticated selection method based on the No. of Students value.

Comment: Or instead of always using sum() you can write sum1, sum2 and sum3 in which you use specific input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use: "onchange" event for textbox

You could use the keyup and keypress events as well.

Eg: `<input type="text" id="input1" onchange="yourFunction()" />`